# Include custom css files in SharePoint CssLink control

Tags: cssregistration

Is it some how possible to include your custom css files in this control?

```
<SharePoint:CssLink runat="server" Version="4"/>
```

I usually wind up inserting the same 3 custom css files in the masterpage whenever I start a new SharePoint project. So I thought since the above control inserts all standard SharePoint stylesheets, I could maybe incluce my own css files in it. But is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use the `CssRegistration` control to add your own CSS files. They are inserted into the page using the CssLink conrol in the masterpage.

Hint: Use the `After` property to load your css file after a specific file, such as 'corev4.css'. This will let you define the load order of your CSS.

You can insert your three instances of `CssRegistration` into a new UserControl in your project, and load this via a Delegate Control in a Feature, to insert your UserControl into the AdditionalPageHead delegate control.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I've already thought of doing this, but thought I might try out the OOTB if it was possible. But if this is the only way, I guess it's good enough as it does what I need it to.